# Writing HTML5 data- to JSON in anonymous function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have a click-through app using data- properties in HTML, then using jQuery, I want to save each selected option to either an array or as an object. But I'm not sure the best way to approach this - I've tried .data() and .map() with no luck.

Essentially I want to just store the data-app value that is clicked (and keep it as JSON format) through each .step iteration. But I'm not sure how to save the data either to an object or array and I can't seem to find a great solution elsewhere. Any help is greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="start step" id="">
        <h2>Select Property Type?</h2>
        <div id="choice" data-app='{"PropertyType" : "single_family"}'>Single Family</div>

        <div id="choice" data-app='{"PropertyType" : "apartment"}'>Apartment</div>

        <div id="choice" data-app='{"PropertyType" : "condo"}'>Condo</div>

        <div id="choice" data-app='{"PropertyType" : "hovel"}'>Hovel</div>
    </div>

    <div class="step" id="">
        <h2>Are you looking to live in Toronto?</h2>
        <div id="choice" data-app='{"LiveInToronto" : "yes"}'>Yes</div>
        <div id="choice" data-app='{"LiveInToronto" : "no"}'>No</div>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
var currentStep = 1;
var num = 1;
var formType = '';
var propertyType = '';
var app = [];

$(this).find('.step').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id', 'step'+num);
    num++;
    $(this).hide();
});



$('.step > #choice').click(function(){
    // propertyType = $(this).data('property-type');
    data = $(this).data('app');
    app = $.map(data, function(value, key){
        return (key + ' ' + value);
    });
    nextStep();
});


console.log(app);

function nextStep() {
        $('#step' + currentStep).hide();
        currentStep++;
        $('#step' + currentStep).fadeIn('fast');
        return currentStep;
    }
```

When using console.log(app) outside of the anonymous function, it returns undefined.

Comment: Is there more to the code? where is num defined? what is `this`? where are all those other vars defined? does it work? If not, why?

Comment: The code has been updated to include variables.

Answer (score -1):

Some issues:

- `console.log(app)` will execute on page load, not when the user clicks, so obviously it will not output what is happening in the anonymous function. If you want to output the result there, you must move the `console.log(app)` statement there.
- In HTML the `id` attribute must have unique values, which is not the case for `choice` in your code. So replace with a `class` attribute instead.
- You are not collecting data into `app`, but overwriting it at each step. You should use `app.push` to not lose the previously stored data
- `this` in top-level code is the `window` object (or `undefined` in strict mode), so `$(this).find('.step')` will not return anything. Use `$(document)` instead.
- It should not be necessary to dynamically assign `id` attribute values. Instead use some smarter selectors.

Here is some modified code:

```js
var app = [];

// hide all steps, except first (don't use this, but document)
$(document).find('.step').slice(1).hide();

$('.step > .choice').click(function(){
    // propertyType = $(this).data('property-type');
    data = $(this).data('app');
    app.push($.map(data, function(value, key){
    // ^^^^^^
        return (key + ' ' + value);
    }));
    console.log(app); // log here!
    nextStep();
});

function nextStep() {
    var $next = $('.step:visible').next('.step');
    $('.step').hide(); // just hide all of them
    $next.fadeIn('fast');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="start step" id="">
    <h2>Select Property Type?</h2>
    <div class="choice" data-app='{"PropertyType" : "single_family"}'>Single Family</div>

    <div class="choice" data-app='{"PropertyType" : "apartment"}'>Apartment</div>

    <div class="choice" data-app='{"PropertyType" : "condo"}'>Condo</div>

    <div class="choice" data-app='{"PropertyType" : "hovel"}'>Hovel</div>
</div>

<div class="step" id="">
    <h2>Are you looking to live in Toronto?</h2>
    <div class="choice" data-app='{"LiveInToronto" : "yes"}'>Yes</div>
    <div class="choice" data-app='{"LiveInToronto" : "no"}'>No</div>
</div>
```

NB: I doubt that the concatenation of key and value into your array is very useful. You lose the structure that you have in your JSON data attributes.

Comment: I would be interested to know why this received a downvote, as I feel this answer is useful.

Comment: Does anyone know how to access the array outside of the anonymous function? Or how you could just save each iteration to a JSON object and access it outside of the anonymous function?